# extracting CAB file throwing error while running as linux container

Tags: c#, linux, docker, sevenzipextractor

I am using `SevenZipExtractor` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipExtractor/) to extract CAB files using below code, it's works on my `windows` machine,

```
using (ArchiveFile archiveFile = new ArchiveFile(@"C:\TEMP\x.cab"))
        {
            foreach (Entry entry in archiveFile.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.FileName);

                // extract to file
                entry.Extract(entry.FileName);

            }
        }
```

While I am pushing this to `Linux` container, it's throws below error,

This seems the NuGet package using some internal Windows DLL.

Question: can I make some docker file change and make it running on Linux container?

```
> ❯ docker run -i test
```

> Unhandled exception. SevenZipExtractor.SevenZipException: Unable to
> initialize SevenZipHandle  ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to
> load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In
> order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG
> environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory    at
> SevenZipExtractor.Kernel32Dll.LoadLibrary(String lpFileName)    at
> SevenZipExtractor.SevenZipHandle..ctor(String sevenZipLibPath)    at
> SevenZipExtractor.ArchiveFile.InitializeAndValidateLibrary()    ---
> End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> SevenZipExtractor.ArchiveFile.InitializeAndValidateLibrary()    at
> SevenZipExtractor.ArchiveFile..ctor(String archiveFilePath, String
> libraryFilePath)    at ConsoleDocker.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /src/Program.cs:line 33

Comment: It seems that it needs kernel32.dll, which is a Windows executable.

Comment: @Jens It does say it supports .NET Standard, so I guess that could be misconstrued as meaning it's cross-platform... maybe? Either way, OP will need to find a cross-platform library.

Comment: It seems like the author doesn't have the inclination to make this work cross-platform (see [GitHub issue 41](https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor/issues/41)).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipExtractor/
C# wrapper for **7z.dll** (included)

You trying to use windows dll under linux.

Instead, you can use https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html - there is pure c# code, not .dll wrapper

Comment: Thanks. this link  `https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html ` details, how to use it?

Comment: Is there any code example please?

Comment: Something like https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder/-/php-sevenzip.compression.lzma.decoder-class-examples.html

Comment: I tried the solution, but it's NOT working for *.CAB files

Comment: We can't see what you did and we don't know what “it's NOT working” means.

Comment: probably for .cab files he need different unpacking algorythm, not 7-zip lzma.